# await fetchAnime doesn't work in Next.js. is there a possible way to fix it?

Tags: next.js

So I've ran into this problem while I was following one of the Youtube tutorials and idk how to fix it. See: [screenshot of error in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fVhD.png)

fetchAnime code:

```
"use server";

const fetchAnime = async (page: number) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://shikimori.one/api/doc/1.0/animes?page=${page}&limit=8=&order=popularatiy"
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
};
```

I've followed tutorial step by step and expected everything to work fine, but I keep encountering this problem.
I tried to update version of Next.js, installed fetch-api

Comment: So the error is telling you that fetchAnime is not defined. Before your use a function it needs to be defined. That measn either you need to import it, or it needs to be defined above the line where you use it. Is that the case? Unfortunately the screenshot does not show any hint of it.

Maybe provide some more context.

Comment: @DustinGogoll oh i actually forgot to write export before const fetchAnime, thanks to you for pointing it out